# Why this code dont work with SendGrid and PHP

Tags: php, email, sendgrid

I'm working on sent emails. I'm using SendGrid account for free but while I'm running my function then it will show me the below error can anyone tell me how I' will resolve it.

```
403 Array ( 
    [0] => HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden 
    [1] => Server: nginx 
    [2] => Date: Wed, 16 Feb 2022 12:30:32 GMT 
    [3] => Content-Type: application/json 
    [4] => Content-Length: 281 
    [5] => Connection: keep-alive 
    [6] => Access-Control-Allow-Origin: https://sendgrid.api-docs.io 
    [7] => Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST 
    [8] => Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Authorization, Content-Type, On-behalf-of, x-sg-elas-acl 
    [9] => Access-Control-Max-Age: 600 
    [10] => X-No-CORS-Reason: https://sendgrid.com/docs/Classroom/Basics/API/cors.html 
    [11] => Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=600; includeSubDomains 
    [12] => 
    [13] => ) {"errors":[{"message":"The from address does not match a verified Sender Identity. Mail cannot be sent until this error is resolved. Visit https://sendgrid.com/docs/for-developers/sending-email/sender-identity/ to see the Sender Identity requirements","field":"from","help":null}
                ]}`
```

Code:

```
<?php
require 'vendor/autoload.php'; 

$email = new \SendGrid\Mail\Mail(); 
$email->setFrom("My email", "Name");
$email->setSubject("Sending with SendGrid is Fun");
$email->addTo("Email when i want to send", "Name");
$email->addContent("text/plain", "and easy to do anywhere, even with PHP");
$email->addContent(
    "text/html", "<strong>and easy to do anywhere, even with PHP</strong>"
);
 $SENDGRID_API_KEY = 'My api key';
$sendgrid = new \SendGrid($SENDGRID_API_KEY);
try {
    $response = $sendgrid->send($email);
    print $response->statusCode() . "\n";
    print_r($response->headers() );
    print $response->body() . "\n";
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo 'Caught exception: '. $e->getMessage() ."\n";
}
```

Comment: The error message is pretty clear: The from address does not match a verified Sender Identity. Mail cannot be sent until this error is resolved. Visit https://sendgrid.com/docs/for-developers/sending-email/sender-identity/ to see the Sender Identity

Comment: Yea, I'm just stupid. Thank bro

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the user didn't even read the error message, which tells them how to solve the problem.